# Simple TDI driver

Tags: c, driver

Can anybody give me a simple TDI driver which can block traffic from specified ip-port, or modify packet. I cant find good manual about this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDI drivers are ***extremely*** complicated. There are companies that sell them for $20,000 and they are worth that price. It would take years to develop and debug a TDI driver. The reason: Windows poorly implemented them, they are part of the network stack itself.

Try using WFP (Windows Filtering Platform) it's an easier interface but doesnt' support Windows XP. Good Luck.